# weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysema.query.dml.UpdateClause

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, querydsl

I am trying to up the weblogic server 12.2.1.4.0, unfortunately it throws ClassNotFoundException for com.mysema.query.dml.UpdateClause class. Below is full error trace of weblogic. However I am not using **com.mysema** dependency and for that I also checked dependency tree for application using maven, this dependency is not there. I also tried to download **querydsl-core-3.7.4.jar** and put into server lib, this also didn't work. Please suggest me some workaround if anyone has faced this kind of issue.

```
<Jun 18, 2020> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "appWebapp [Version=10.2.0_40.0.0]" due to error weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysema.query.dml.UpdateClause
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysema.query.dml.UpdateClause
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:132)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:244)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:66)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysema.query.dml.UpdateClause
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:101)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jun 18, 2020> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "appWebapp [Version=10.2.0_40.0.0]".
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try providing the following dependency in your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

In my case it did the trick.